# [NSProgress cancel]_block_invoke crash, maybe in AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, exc-bad-access, weak-references

I got 118 crash reports (from a single user) via Firebase:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000010
Crashed: com.apple.root.background-qos
0  Foundation                     0x18287a4b4 __20-[NSProgress cancel]_block_invoke_3 + 16
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x1816bea54 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x1816bea14 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x1816cbea4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1032
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x1816cba38 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 120
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18196706c _pthread_wqthread + 1268
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x181966b6c start_wqthread + 4
```

Checking the documentation for `[NSProgress cancel]`, it looks like it will invoke the `cancellationHandler` block on the `NSProgress` object. I've searched my project for one of those blocks and the only one I found was in AFNetworking (`AFURLSessionManager.m`).

```
__weak __typeof__(task) weakTask = task;
for (NSProgress *progress in @[ _uploadProgress, _downloadProgress ])
{
    progress.totalUnitCount = NSURLSessionTransferSizeUnknown;
    progress.cancellable = YES;
    progress.cancellationHandler = ^{
        [weakTask cancel];
    };
    ...
```

My guess is that `weakTask` is invalid and that is what is causing the crash. It doesn't appear to be `nil` though, because the invalid address was `0x0000000000000010` and not just `0x00`.

Is there a way I can validate a weak reference before using it? I'd like to try fixing it locally before submitting a bug report/fix to AFNetworking.

Comment: Try to capture the task as a __strong reference inside the block before calling `cancel`

Comment: Definitely not that - if weakTask is nil then there will not be a problem. I think it is *inside* the ```[weakTask cancel]``` that the problem lies. Can you give more details on ```task``` - specifically ```[task cancel]```

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I have the same problem